# Magento 2.1.9 - Can not acces Magento API log file. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-5b7e549729324

Tags: magento, magento2.1

We are trying to access via rest-API and search orders via `[increment_id]`, so we are using this GET:

```
<web>/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[increment_id][value]=068550002
```

Is this line correct? As an answer I get:

> {
>       "message": "Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-5b7e549729324"
>   }

[image]

But I can't access `var/report/api`, there isn't any folder created.

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: Could we see the code you are running?

Comment: This is native Magento, there is no different code. I can edit and add the native code from Magento where they call API.

Comment: I meant the code that you're using to call the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one:

> web/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=increment_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=086160005&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq

It works for me.